# python thread cleanup after completion

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using this pattern for some threading tasks that are one-shots.  In other words they go and do a finite job and flow out of the `run()` function when they're done.

Besides destroying my reference to this object after it's job is complete, do I need to do any other clean up?  Such as calling `join()`?

```
import threading
import Queue
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):                                           
    def __init__(self, shared_queue):    
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        if isinstance(shared_queue, Queue.Queue):
            self.shared_queue = shared_queue
        else:
            raise ValueError('shared_queue invalid type.')                                                                      
        self.start()                                                           

    def run(self):                                                             
        self.shared_queue.put('hello world')
        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: the only thing 'join()' does is wait for the thread to end. If you know the threads have ended before finishing your script, then no.

Comment: Cool.  I wasn't sure if it was gonna leave zombie threads around like `fork()` will if you don't call `wait()`